# Unable to checkout multiple repositories to a single directory

Tags: git, ansible

Following is the playbook that I'm trying to run.

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo : true
  sudo_user : ganesh

  tasks:
  - name: git repo clone
    git: repo=https://ganesh:mypassword@github.com/myrepo/root-repo.git dest=/home/ganesh/rootrepo version=master recursive=no
    git: repo=https://ganesh:mypassword@github.com/myrepo/subrepo1.git dest=/home/ganesh/rootrepo/subrepo1 version=master recursive=no
    git: repo=https://ganesh:mypassword@github.com/myrepo/subrepo2.git dest=/home/ganesh/rootrepo/subrepo2 version=master recursive=no
    git: repo=https://ganesh:mypassword@github.com/myrepo/subrepo3.git dest=/home/ganesh/rootrepo/subrepo3 version=master recursive=no
```

I'm expecting the following directory structure after running this playbook.

```
rootrepo
    - root repo contents
    - subrepo1
        - subrepo1 contents
    - subrepo2
        - subrepo2 contents
    - subrepo3
        - subrepo3 contents
```

But there is only one repo,i.e.,***subrepo3***, remaining under ***rootrepo*** directory after the playbook is executed. Everything else is getting deleted. Even ***rootrepo*** contents are getting deleted.

```
rootrepo
    - subrepo3
        - subrepo3 contents
```

Why is it so? How can achieve the directory structure that I'm expecting?

Comment: You should use [git submodule](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: Thanks @keltar for the reply. Is there a way to execute this git submodule in ansible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation as to why this isn't working as exepected is that Ansible plays are read in as yaml files and "tasks" is a list of dictionaries.  In your case you are duplicating the module "git" (a key in the dictionary) so the last one wins.

To do exactly what you want the following play will work

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo : true
  sudo_user : ganesh

  tasks:
  - name: git repo clone
    git: repo=https://ganesh:mypassword@github.com/myrepo/root-repo.git dest=/home/ganesh/rootrepo version=master recursive=no
  - name: clone subrepos
    git: repo=https://ganesh:mypassword@github.com/myrepo/{{ item }}.git dest=/home/ganesh/rootrepo/{{ item }} version=master recursive=no
    with_items:
      - subrepo1
      - subrepo2
      - subrepo3
```

In general though, it is not a good idea to have repositories checked out in other repositories.
More likely what you want to do is add subrepo{1,2,3} as submodules to root-repo.

Assuming you have commit access to your root repo clone it and then run.

```
git submodule add https://ganesh:mypassword@github.com/myrepo/subrepo1.git subrepo1
git submodule add https://ganesh:mypassword@github.com/myrepo/subrepo2.git subrepo2
git submodule add https://ganesh:mypassword@github.com/myrepo/subrepo3.git subrepo3
```

Check in those changes and then in your play set recursive=true when you checkout root-repo.git

Comment: Thanks @jarv. Its working when I created seperate tasks for cloning sub-repos. It seems like your suggestion of using `submodule` and `recursive=true` makes the work simple, but what if I want to checkout different branches for root module and submodules i.e., `master` branch for root module and some `dev` branch for submodule.